# Odoo 10 - store user id of current session in form on submission

Tags: session, foreign-keys, odoo, odoo-10

Relatively new to Odoo. Was trying to put a relation whereby 1 email is sent by 1 user but 1 user can send many email. I created a Many2one field in the email class as shown

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='user id', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```

When i submit from the form, it always stores "1" which is the ID of the admin even if i log in as another user (John doe with id=6).

To check whether the relation is good, i just displayed the user_id field in my form, and I see a dropdown is populated with all the users in the database as shown in the codes below

```
<div class="hff hff_dropbox form-group" data-form-type="dropbox" data-field-id="4">
    <label class="control-label" for="user_id">User id</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user_id">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <option value="1">Administrator</option>
        <option value="6">John Doe</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in odoo backend **uid, user** is the orm fields which will store the logged in user in default. If you need to get it from code, try

```
self.env.user.id or request.session.uid or self.env.context.get('uid')
```